# Create points from CSV file using csv.reader

Tags: arcpy

Trying to create a script that will plot points from a csv table. My issue is that the points aren't being plotted. The fields are being updated, but not plotted. I am trying to use decimal degrees at the lat and long fields but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I change my code to plot the points and update the rows? The out_points input is an empty point layer with those three fields added to it. And I wanted to plot the points within this layer using the CSV.

```
# create points from csv
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(out_points, ['SHAPE@', 'ID', 'LAT', 'LONG']) as cursor:
    point = arcpy.Point()
    with open(csvfile) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        headers = next(reader)
        for line in reader:
            point.ID = line[0]
            point.X = line[2]
            point.Y = line[1]
            cursor.insertRow((point, point.ID, point.X, point.Y))
```

Comment: [Make XY event layer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm) would be alot easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are inserting a point object instead of PointGeometry object.

try this

```
# create points from csv
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(out_points, ['SHAPE@', 'ID', 'LAT', 'LONG']) as cursor:
    point = arcpy.Point()
    with open(csvfile) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        headers = next(reader)
        for line in reader:
            point.ID = line[0]
            point.X = line[2]
            point.Y = line[1]
            geom = arcpy.PointGeometry(point)
            cursor.insertRow((geom, point.ID, point.X, point.Y))
```

Also make sure you aren't switching lon and lat. I think lat should be Y and lon should be X.